# Not getting to the if statements the are nested in a switch Statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

## Do not take my question down before reading this, please.

#### My code is not even getting inside the if statements(*I tested this with console.logs*). There is not a similar answer to this that I have seen. I even added a use effect which would fix it if it was a timing/ asynchronous issue

### Objective:

> I want to test to see if the value of any of the pairs is an empty string. if it is I am setting it equal to a static value that's already in my code(**Under** ***bout***).

---

#### Please note:

###### I am aware that the easiest way to solve this problem is to set default states, however, I would like to know why what I have implemented here is not working. Also, I don't know why this question was marked as having a similar answer, that has to do with setting state... My code is not getting into the if statements at all!

---

### Problem:

> The problem is that no matter what it seems I am not getting into *any* of the if statements. Whether I test if the value is **false** (*Empty strings should be falsely value*) or if I just straight-up test to see if they are a string (*which I know they are*) either way. All of the values in theFinalEdited bout are pieces of individual **state** from **controled react inputs**

## What I thought was the problem:

> The reason why this code does not work is that **state is IMUTTABLE** This means you can not change the value of state since each key value is an actual piece of **state** you must set each one of those respectively. Each value in **theFinalEditedBout** is its own piece of **state** that is from a controlled react input that correlates to a form.

### Code :

```js
         const takeInTheInputs = () => {

        let theFinalEditedBout = {
            topLineWrestler,
            bottomLineWrestler,
            dispatched,
            dispatchedToMat,
            winner,
            loser,
            matchNumber,
            round,
            score,
            userID: 1
        };


        (function () {
            let arrayOfKeyValuePairs = Object.entries(theFinalEditedBout);
            arrayOfKeyValuePairs.map((keyPair, index) => {
                console.log({ index, keyPair })

                switch (index) {
                    case 0:
                        console.log(`I got to case ${index}`);
                        console.log({ keyPairString: keyPair[1] });
                        if (keyPair[1] === '') {
                            setTopLineWrestler(bout.top_line_wrestler);
                            break;
                        } else {
                            break;
                        }
                    case 1:
                        console.log(`I got to case ${index}`)
                        console.log({ keyPairString: keyPair[1] });
                        if (keyPair[1] === '') {
                            setBottomLineWrestler(bout.bottom_line_wrestler);
                            // bout.bottomLineWrestler = bout.bottom_line_wrestler;
                            break;
                        } else {
                            break;
                        }
                    case 2:
                        console.log(`I got to case ${index}`)
                        console.log({ keyPairString: keyPair[1] });
                        if (keyPair[1] === '') {
                            setDispatched(bout.dispatched);
                            // bout.dispatched = bout.dispatched;
                            break;
                        } else {
                            break;
                        }
                    case 3:
                        console.log(`I got to case ${index}`)
                        console.log({ keyPairString: keyPair[1] });
                        if (keyPair[1] = '') {
                            setDispatchedToMat(12)
                            // bout.dispatchedToMat = bout.dispatched_to_mat;
                            break;
                        } else {
                            break;
                        }
                    case 4:
                        console.log(`I got to case ${index}`)
                        console.log({ keyPairString: keyPair[1] });
                        if (keyPair[1] === '') {
                            console.log("I am in")
                            setWinner(bout.winner)
                            // bout.winner = bout.winner;
                            break;
                        } else {
                            break;
                        }
                    case 5:
                        console.log(`I got to case ${index}`)
                        console.log({ keyPairString: keyPair[1] });
                        if (keyPair[1] === '') {
                            setLoser(bout.loser)
                            // bout.loser = bout.loser;
                            break;
                        } else {
                            break;
                        }
                    case 6:
                        console.log(`I got to case ${index}`)
                        console.log({ keyPairString: keyPair[1] });
                        if (keyPair[1] === '') {
                            setMatchNumber(bout.match_number);
                            // bout.matchNumber = bout.match_number;
                            break;
                        } else {
                            break;
                        }
                    case 7:
                        console.log(`I got to case ${index}`)
                        console.log({ keyPairString: keyPair[1] });
                        if (keyPair[1] === '') {
                            setRound(bout.round)
                            // bout.round = bout.round;
                            break;
                        } else {
                            break;
                        }
                    case 8:
                        console.log(`I got to case ${index}`)
                        console.log({ keyPairString: keyPair[1] });
                        if (keyPair[1] === '') {
                            setScore(bout.score)
                            // bout.score = bout.score;
                            break;
                        } else {
                            break;
                        }
                }
                console.log({
                    theFinalEditedBout,
                    bout
                });

            })

            useEffect(() => {
                setEditOfBout({
                    topLineWrestler,
                    bottomLineWrestler,
                    dispatched,
                    dispatchedToMat: Number(dispatchedToMat),
                    winner,
                    loser,
                    matchNumber,
                    round,
                    score,
                    userID: 1
                });
            }, [topLineWrestler,
                bottomLineWrestler,
                dispatched,
                dispatchedToMat,
                winner,
                loser,
                matchNumber,
                round,
                score,])
        })();

        const requestOptions = {
            method: "PUT",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                // Authorization: `Bearer token`,
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(editOfBout),
        };

        fetch(`/api/bouts/${BoutId}`, requestOptions).then((res) => {
            if (res.ok) {

            } else {
                alert("it didn't work! Coach Wayne Apologizes try again later");
            }
        });



    }
```

### Where the function is called

```html
    return (
        <Form style={{ width: "90%", border: "2px solid slateGrey", borderRadius: "5px" }} className="mx-auto bg-dark text-light mt-2 p-2">

            <Form.Group className="mb-3" >
                <Form.Label>topLineWrestler</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control onChange={(e) => setTopLineWrestler(e.target.value)} type="text" placeholder="Enter email" />
                <Form.Text className="text-muted">
                    We'll never share your email with anyone else.
                </Form.Text>
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group className="mb-3" >
                <Form.Label>bottomLineWrestler</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control onChange={(e) => setBottomLineWrestler(e.target.value)} type="text" placeholder="Password" />
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group className="mb-3" >
                <Form.Label>dispatched</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control onChange={(e) => setDispatched(e.target.value)} type="number" placeholder="0 ===''  1 = true" />
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group className="mb-3" >
                <Form.Label>dispatchedToMat</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control onChange={(e) => setDispatchedToMat(e.target.value)} type="text" placeholder="text" />
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group className="mb-3" >
                <Form.Label>winner</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control onChange={(e) => setWinner(e.target.value)} type="text" placeholder="Password" />
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group className="mb-3" >
                <Form.Label>loser</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control onChange={(e) => setLoser(e.target.value)} type="text" placeholder="Password" />
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group className="mb-3" >
                <Form.Label>matchNumber</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control onChange={(e) => setMatchNumber(e.target.value)} type="text" placeholder="Password" />
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group className="mb-3" >
                <Form.Label>Round</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control onChange={(e) => setRound(e.target.value)} type="text" placeholder="Password" />
            </Form.Group>

            <Form.Group className="mb-3" >
                <Form.Label>Score</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control onChange={(e) => setScore(e.target.value)} type="text" placeholder="Password" />
            </Form.Group>

            <Button variant="primary" type="button" onClick={takeInTheInputs}>
                Submit
            </Button>
        </Form>
```

## console.logs

- #### editOfBout: {}
- #### KeyPairString: Logs an empty string on most keys
- #### theFinalEditedBout: Logs it's starting Values
- #### bout:

```js
{
bottom_line_wrestler: "{\"name\":\"bye\",\"team\":\"bye\",\"seed\":20}"
created_at: "2022-03-02T17:43:32.000Z"
created_by_user: 1
dispatched: 0
dispatched_to_mat: null
division_id: 3
event_division_bout_concatenated: "e2d3b7"
event_id: 2
id: 133
loser: null
match_number: 7
round: 1
score: null
top_line_wrestler: "{\"name\":\"bye\",\"team\":\"bye\",\"seed\":13}"
winner: null
}
```

Comment: I don't see where `takeInTheInputs` is called. Please include all relevant code in your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example If possible, a *running* codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I feel you rely on all setters too much, thinking that it will be executed immediately (not async) and then use setEditOfBout with all the values-states.

In short, setState's are async - meaning they are not executed immediately. For example in your code (abstract):

```js
function foo() {
  const val = Math.random();
  setScore(val);
  setEditOfBout({score});
}
```

will not change score in `editOfBout` because score will be updated later while setEditOfBout will use current value.

Instead, consider (simplifying your code first! and next) doing something like this:

```js
function foo() {
  const val = Math.random();
  setScore(val);
  setEditOfBout({score: val}); // <- HERE, don't use state score value
}
```

Comment: What I did was I put the setEditOfBout in a useEffect where it runs whenever one of the states we are trying to set changes.  And I am still getting empty strings, with your logic this shouldn't have happened correct? Or am I misUnderstanding

Comment: That's not my logic, that's how react's states work... Unless you show minimal code that we can run, I would say you probably misunderstood and you should reconsider structure of your states. Good luck.